# Examples with cvAbsDiff?

Tags: java, image, opencv, javacv

I am trying to find the difference between two pictures, however, I am using JavaCV and while I have found a openCV function that seems to do what I need I can't seem to get it to work as I am not sure how I can use the cvAbsDiff in java. Can anyone provide an example of what imports I would need and where I can find a list of the supported openCV functions in javaCV?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use in the following form:

```
cvAbsDiff(image1, image2, result);
```

You need to import

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*
```

to enable the absdiff.